# How to define custom getter and setter for a custom widget? - Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

For a custom widget that inherits from _WidgetBase what is the pattern for defining custom getter and setter?  The confusion I have is that in the documentation for dojo Stateful (which is supposedly inherited by _WidgetBase) it defines the following pattern

> ```
> fooBar: null,
> _fooBarGetter: function(){
>   return this.fooBar;
> },
> _fooBarSetter: function(value){
>   this.fooBar = value;
> },
> ```

so in general _xxxGetter and _xxxSetter
where xxx is the exact name of the property

However in the documentation for _WidgetBase the pattern shown in the examples looks like this

> ```
> // for the field "foo" in your widget:
>
> // custom getter
> _getFooAttr: function(){ /* do something and return a value */ },
>
> // custom setter
> _setFooAttr: function(value){ /* do something to set a value */ }
> ```

Which first of all the name of the property in the getter/setter doesn't match exactly with the actual property defined in the comment, and second is completely different pattern than that seen in Stateful documentation.

So which one is it?

Comment: Use `Proxy()` [Proxy MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a dijit/widget, by inheriting `_WidgetBase`. you need to follow the documentation for `_WidgetBase`.

If you are creating a module which inherits `Stateful` module(which is not a dijit), then you follow the documentation for `Stateful`.

To clarify your doubt, `_WidgetBase` custom getter/setter overrides the methods of `Stateful`. So if you are creating a widget, you need the custom getter/setter to be in the format of `_getXxxxAttr`/`_setXxxxAttr`

**UPDATE:**
The issue is not the format of the custom setter. The setter would set the value, even you if don't have a custom getter/setter. It will create a new property and store the value. If the goal is just to store a value as property in the object, you dont need the custom setter/getter. But that would be not good as a coding standard (Not going to debate about that here).

If you have some other change or event due to updating the property, then you would need to have the custom getter or setter as described in the documentation. Below is a snippet, which will show you the difference between the formats. Observe result, and how and which properties are updated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
  <script>
    require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dojo/Stateful"], function(declare, _WidgetBase, Stateful) {

      var CustomDijit = declare([_WidgetBase], {
        _customname: "",
        greeting: "",

        _getNameAttr: function() {
          return this._customname;
        },

        _setNameAttr: function(value) {
          this._customname = value;
          this.greeting = "Hello " + this._customname + "!";
        }
      });

      var CustomDijit2 = declare([_WidgetBase], {
        _customname: "",
        greeting: "",

        _nameGetter: function() {
          return this._customname;
        },

        _nameSetter: function(value) {
          this._customname = value;
          this.greeting = "Hello " + this._customname + "!";
        }
      });

      var obj = new CustomDijit();
      obj.set("name", "Jeff");

      console.log(obj.get("name"));
      console.log(obj._customname);
      console.log(obj.name);
      console.log(obj.greeting);

      var obj2 = new CustomDijit2();
      obj2.set("name", "Jeff");

      console.log(obj2.get("name"));
      console.log(obj2._customname);
      console.log(obj2.name);
      console.log(obj2.greeting);

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, one interesting observation, when watching a variable for changes, the watch callback only fires when you use _set for widgetBase style getter, setter (ie. _setXxxxAttr) and when using Stateful it fires when using set (without underscore)  Also The statefule method of getting setting also works in a custom widget when inheriting only from _WidgetBase and watch works fine as well.